# Wildfly8.1 DB password hardcoded in standalone.xml

Tags: wildfly-8

The password of the DB user is hard coded in the standalone.xml of the WildFly8.1.The requirement is to read password from a binary file and using that password for login into DB .Hibernate is used for reading the information from DB.Can you please tell me what steps I should follow to fulfill this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

loki

Answer (score 1):

In WildFly VaultTool is used for secured attributes (e.g. passwords) which can be later on used in configuration files in masked form

```
<security>  
    <user-name>user_name</user-name>  
    <password>${VAULT::ds_OraXADS::password::N2NhZDYzOTMtNWE0OS00ZGQ0LWE4MmEtMWNlMDMyNDdmNmI2TElORV9CUkVBS3ZhdWx0}</password>  
</security>
```

[JBoss AS7 Securing Passwords](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecuringPasswords)